# How to get callback when Spring web aplication is finished starting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servletcontextlistener, servlet-listeners

I have some action I need to perform after the entire spring application has finished loading. The action must happen after all beans are inititlized and all controllers can start serving requests.

I tried implementing a ServletContextListener and adding it as a listener in  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer but this happens as soon as the application boot up and not after. Also I am not using SpringBoot avaiable to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using spring mvc.

So RequestHandledEvent will fulfill your requirement.

```
RequestHandledEvent

This is a web-specific event telling all beans that an HTTP request has been serviced.
```

More detail about spring event

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm

Comment: Won't This will happen only after a request gets processed so it won't get trigger at all if no Rest Api is called.

Comment: Do you try to print out the log and how is the result for ContextStartedEvent, ContextRefreshedEvent and RequestHandledEvent